# Android Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I am trying to work through the coroutines code lab from Google:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#0

When I build the project I get the error:

More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'

To fix it, I found some answers that suggest packaging options should be included in the Android block of my Gradle file:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module'
    }
}
```

It does solves that error, but then when I try and install the app onto a device I get another error that I can't make sense of:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Zach/Desktop/android-coroutines/kotlin-coroutines/kotlin-coroutines-start/app/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk_resources/debug/instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug/out/slice_3/resources_ap
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as far as finding out exactly what went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is bug in `kotlinx.coroutines` version `1.2.0` that is due to be fixed in version `1.2.1`. See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1064